# Capture from 1st occurance of x to nth occurance of y

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a regular expression problem that seems fairly do-able, but i can't seem to be able to get correct.

Give strings that look like:

```
id1234|a; b; c; d
id5678|a; b; e; f
id9012|a; g; h; i
```

I'm trying to capture from the pipe to a fixed occurrence of the semicolon, intuitively I'd expect something like:

```
"(?<=\\|)(([^;]*;){1}[^;]*).*"
```

to select from the pipe up to the 2nd semicolon, since:

```
"^(([^;]*;){1}[^;]*).*"
```

selects from the beginning of the line to the 2nd semicolon.

https://regexr.com/

believes that:

```
(?<=\|)(([^;]*;){1}[^;]*).*
```

Correctly selects from the pipe onward, but appears to fail to end the capture at the correct semicolon.

But in R gsub complains:

```
a <- c("id1234|a; b; c; d",
       "id5678|a; b; e; f",
       "id9012|a; g; h; i",
       "id3456|a; j; k; l")

b <- gsub(pattern = "^(([^;]*;){1}[^;]*).*",
          replacement = "\\1",
          x = a)
b
[1] "id1234|a; b" "id5678|a; b" "id9012|a; g" "id3456|a; j"

c <- gsub(pattern = "(?<=\\|)(([^;]*;){1}[^;]*).*",
          replacement = "\\1",
          x = a)
Error in gsub(pattern = "(?<=\\|)(([^;]*;){1}[^;]*).*", replacement = "\\1",  : 
  invalid regular expression '(?<=\|)(([^;]*;){1}[^;]*).*', reason 'Invalid regexp'
In addition: Warning message:
In gsub(pattern = "(?<=\\|)(([^;]*;){1}[^;]*).*", replacement = "\\1",  :
  TRE pattern compilation error 'Invalid regexp'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you are using a lookbehind, `(?<=\|)`, but did not use the `perl=TRUE` argument to enable the PCRE regex engine that supports lookbehinds. The default TRE regex engine does not support lookarounds.

You need to match the whole string:

```r
sub("^[^|]*\\|([^;]*;[^;]*).*", "\\1", a)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HDEe5j/1) and the [R demo](https://ideone.com/gke5Qc):

```r
a <- c("id1234|a; b; c; d",
       "id5678|a; b; e; f",
       "id9012|a; g; h; i",
       "id3456|a; j; k; l")
sub("^[^|]*\\|([^;]*;[^;]*).*", "\\1", a)
## => [1] "a; b" "a; b" "a; g" "a; j"
```

*Regex details*:

- `^` - string start
- `[^|]*` - zero or more chars other than `|`
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `([^;]*;[^;]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `;`, `;` and again any zero or more chars other than `;`
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

If you want to *extract*, you should actually use the *extracting* regex methods, for example:

```r
a <- c("id1234|a; b; c; d", "id5678|a; b; e; f", "id9012|a; g; h; i", "id3456|a; j; k; l")
unlist(regmatches(a, gregexpr("(?<=\\|)[^;]*;[^;]*", a, perl=TRUE)))
## => [1] "a; b" "a; b" "a; g" "a; j"

library(stringr)
str_extract(a, "(?<=\\|)[^;]*;[^;]*")
## => [1] "a; b" "a; b" "a; g" "a; j"
```